# might or may; would or will

Tags: modal-verbs

1. You might say we do business a little differently, but we wouldn't have it any other way.
2. You may say we do business a little differently, but we won't have it any other way.

Unilever use #1 in its website, instead of #2. Why would Unilever use something of past tense instead of present tense to describe things happening now?

[Unilever website](https://www.unilever.com/brands/home-care/seventh-generation/)

Comment: There is no 'past tense' in those sentences.

Answer (score 1):

*Might* can sometimes be the past tense of *may.* If something *might have happened* in the past, there was a possibility of its happening at that time. If it *may have happened* recently, we don't yet know whether it has or not.

However, *may* and *might* are often treated as synonyms.

As for *would* and *will* - *we wouldn't have it any other way* is an idiom meaning 'This is the way we like it - if a different way was possible we wouldn't choose it'. *We won't have it any other way* would mean 'We refuse to consider another way'.